# Box2D grid based collision

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

First let me quickly tell what I am trying. I am doing tetris-like game using Box2D, I know Box2D is maybe not the best option in this case, but I really need to have normal physics also because the levels have obstacles and if you hit them blocks are supposed to rotate.

Here is image to demonstrate what I mean.

[image]

**Case 1:**
This is how I want it to be.

**Case 2:**
This was one of my ideas, just to make the block size of falling piece little bit smaller so they fit nicely into the empty space. As expected problem with this was the empty space around the block. Making it look like box doesn't belong there.

**Case 3:**
Keeping the block size of falling piece same as "wall" block size it never makes it to the empty space, because edges collide and it stays like that.

so how can I make it fit in empty space filling it and without looking weird?

**EDIT:** If I make size of the falling object smaller it wont work in this case:
[image]

And here is image to demonstrate what kind of behavior I want:

[image]

Comment: I'd say you can use normal Box2d physics until you get close to where the piece will fit in, then disable the physics and write your own logic that will compensate and have the block fit as long as it's 'close enough'.  Also http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ might be a better resource for such a question

Comment: I'd recommend not to use a physics engine for this. It's juts fraught with problems, and you'll end up like http://xkcd.com/724/. And if blocks can have arbitrary rotation, how are you going to detect when a line is filled?

Comment: I dont need to check if line is filled. Player is revarded by how many blocks he could fit in level

Comment: I agree on not using the physics engine (and I am a big fan of using them).  I saw this game implemented in C# (http://www.amazon.com/Professional-XNA-Programming-Building-Windows/dp/0470261285) roughly 5 years ago.  You can do it without the physics.

Comment: If scoring is done by how many blocks the player can fit in, then it seems like you don't really need tiles at all, and the middle example (2) in your first image should be ok. But I guess you could detect which tile squares are filled by the block once it has come to rest, and replace it with full-sized squares.

Comment: but I only check it at the end of level, so I need next blocks to fit well with the previous ones

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Use setFixedRotation(true) on your body.
2) Make it little smaller than available space (from both sides). Make the difference so small that effect would be invisible (yet it will be sufficient for box2d).
This should fix your problem.
Edges won't touch, but if necessary you can try removing friction as well.
Note:
Using a physics engine might be an overkill in your use case, but it is not a that bad idea since you won't have to do much if you use it properly.
Good luck.

**Update:**
1) Don't make objects small. Make them thin. :)
[image: Small vs Thin]
This should solve your first problem.
2) If you want behavior shown in next case, you are expecting free rotation while falling + correct orientation when touching ground. These two things inherently contradict each other.

I would suggest to rethink your strategy. But still if you are determined to do it the same way, there are some weird ways to achieve it (nothing is impossible, right?).
The one I could think of right now is implementing a tendency of all objects to go to nearest right orientation all the time (external moment as a function of current orientation). It should be updated in render. It is effectively a control system, but there is no guarantee that the orientation would be achieved by the time it is going to collide and the physics won't look natural too. Just try to expand your imagination and have fun. I would certainly like to see it if you find out a better way.
Enjoy.

Comment: But If I make it even just a little bit smaller, even 0,0000001% it will not work in case where shape is "U" shape and it has to fit around other blocks in the middle. I edited my question and added explanation image.

Comment: I haven't yet implemented it, but I think you have a point and this is probably the right ( or only ) way to do it